# Websocket-client always closed connection (Python)

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to set up a websocket on python (3.9.0) with visual studio code on MacOS X (11.2.3).
Regrettably I don't get the connection running. I immediately receive a "closed connection" output.
I already have tried to run the code on PyCharm... same result. I have already googled, but no offered solution was helpful for me.

Here is my code, it is absolutely basic:

```
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://echo.websocket.org"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')
    ws.send("hi")
def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message.upper())
    ws.close()

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open,
     on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Best wishes.